# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to import Tensorflow 2.10 using Python 3.8.5, but I received this following error:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I think I accidentally install Intel GPU extention on my machine while I'm using a GTX GPU that has CUDA on it. Please help

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by deleting all plugin files in the tensorflow-plugins directory of ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages